# HttpModule is executed for JS/CSS/Images

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-6, httpmodule, ihttpmodule

**Problem:** HttpModule is executed for JS/CSS/Images.

Following is current Configuration/Settings:

**Infrastructure:**

IIS 6.0 on Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2, Enterprise Edition, Service Pack 2

**IIS VD settings:**

Wildcard application mapping to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll 
UnChecked "Verify that file exists"

**Technology:**

.NET Framework 4.0 + ASP.NET + ASP .NET Web API

**Web.config configuration:**

```
 <httpModules><add name="BeforeProcessRequest" type="UI.Web.ApplicationCode.BeforeProcessRequest,UI.Web"/>
```

```
 <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">      
  <add name="BeforeProcessRequest" type="UI.Web.ApplicationCode.BeforeProcessRequest,UI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
</modules>

 <handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
</handlers>
 </system.webServer>
```

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Does [this questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387427/requests-for-static-files-are-hitting-the-managed-code-in-asp-net-mvc3) and its answer help you?

Comment: Can anyone help to solve this ? Thanks!